# Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_intel_thread.dylib. in Julia Pluto Notebook in MacOS M1

Tags: julia, pluto

I am getting Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_intel_thread.dylib. a message every time I run a Pluto notebook in Julia. I updated Julia to 1.6 and Pluto to a newer version but no changes. I have tried everything that comes to my mind and query results on the internet but it is really frustrating not to find any solution to this problem.
I am adding screenshots to a clear understanding of the problem. I use macOS Big Sur version 11.2.3 on Apple M1 Macbook. [image]

Comment: Are the errors the same outside Pluto? A first step is to eliminate that. But presumably the Rosetta emulation isn't going to emulate Intel MKL though - the "Intel's Outside" now?

Comment: The problem is not related to Pluto. I have confirmed that it is related to Julia. It gives exact same error even if I do not start Pluto notebook. @daycaster

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.julia/conda/3/lib julia
```

Relevant issue: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6423

Answer (score 0):

The other solution which worked for me as point out here: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/315#issuecomment-814652753

```
using Conda
Conda.rm("mkl")
Conda.add("nomkl")
```